# javascript function for server side validation using wcf

Tags: javascript, wcf

I am using a wcf service to authenticate a user. the service returns a true or false based on whether the username/password are valid/invalid. how do I pass the returned value to the javascript function to decide whether the authentication failed or passed.

```
       function AuthenticateUser(email, password, onSuccess, onFailed) 
     {

             var person = { "Email": $("#Email").val(), "Password": $("#Password").val() };
             req = $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: JSON.stringify(person),
                 url: wsUrl + "/AuthenticateUser",
                 success: function ()
                  {
                     req = null;
                     onSuccess();
                 },
                 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     if (textStatus != 'abort')
                         onFailed(errorThrown);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO its good enough just to add your expected result as parameter to your onSuccess method, like:

```
   function onSuccess(result) 
:
...
}
```

See [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/12/28/create-an-ajax-enabled-wcf-service-and-invoking-it-using-client-side-code.aspx) for example.